# live site don't load when taking backup

Tags: backup, schedule

we are taking scheduled backup everyday, we have some 3000 products and it add more....

its a live site and usually we will keep scheduled backup night time.

it take about 2 hours for taking complete system backup.

at the time the backup is going on , the site will not load.

is there any way to run the site as normal when we are taking scheduled backup or normal backup